# Getting Log of Windows Kernel through Serial Port

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, qemu, com-port

I am making a driver for windows kernel and I am using COM1 for getting log of kernel, the host machine is Ubuntu and guest is qemu. Windows 10 is installed inside it. The problem is there is a bulk of data to be write on COM1. So if it has to write a line **ABCDEFGHI** and in the next line, it has to write **JKLMNOPQ**.. it is doing something like **ABCDEF** in one line and **GHIJKLMNOPQ** in the second line, means one line data is incomplete and 2nd line data is also corrupting due to this.. is there any lock we can apply? that if one connection is using COM1 then no any other should write on COM1?

Answer (score 0):

QEMU does not control who can write to serial port address at certain time. It's the guest OS's job. QEMU just receives whatever data it sees in the virtual registers.

If you really need to write bulk data to the serial port in the guest OS, you would expect very long time of process. I ever had the same problem and had to test the speed on a very fast Intel CPU. The best speed I can get is 220KBps.

If processing time is not a problem for you, from guest Windows perspective, if you directly write to COM1's port address, it's your driver's responsibility to make locking mechanism, assuming there is no other drivers/processes writing to COM1 either. If you write data via a handle to the COM1 device, there is no locking provided directly by Windows built-in serial port driver. But you still can do it in other ways: open a handle to the serial port device exclusively, so only one process can write to it, or make a device filter driver sitting above Windows serial port driver to add this additional access control, or even directly modify Windows serial port driver's source code to add what you want. Its source code is available now on github.

If none of above applies to your case, you might want to double check how you capture the output of COM1 on host, usually redirected to files, shell and etc. They also could cause some mystery of troubles.